Prove that every decidable but non-regular language contains an unrecognizable subset
Let A = {L ⊆ Σ∗ ∣ L is decidable but not regular}, which means A is the set of all languages that are decidable but not regular.
I need to prove that every L ∈ A contains an unrecognizable subset.
For example, if L ∈ A, it is decidable but not regular. I suspect that I can construct a subset L′⊆L L′ is unrecognizable (i.e., no Turing machine can semi-decide L′). I am not sure how to formally construct such a subset or prove this rigorously.
Can someone provide a formal proof or explain the reasoning behind this claim?

Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.
